# LaTeX - font manipulation

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am writing LaTeX code and I am trying to adjust the font in the generated pdf document to be Garamond. So I used fontspec package and wrote this line of code:

```
\setmainfont{Garamond}
```

and compiled the code using LuaLatex instead of pdfLatex.
But the desired font was not generated and I checked the log file and found this:

```
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Garamond/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'Garamond(0)' created for font 'Garamond'
```

Any help?

Comment: Please post a full MWE.

Comment: What @Ingmar is saying is that to post a code that can run on its own in a latex editor. You may add dummy text or lorem(use `\lipsum[1]` instead of the text) text and create a dummy file for this - but make sure it includes the parts of the problem. What you are doing is condensing your real document and removing sensitive information.

Comment: No real Garamond font has boldface, which came into fashion much later than Garamond's times.

Comment: @ingmar But I personally think that MWE is not needed to parse/describe the issue but will be needed to identify the problem and solve it.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but most available implementations actually provide bold (all the ones in my answer do).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a “Garamond” font installed on your system? I don’t know a font going exactly by that name, because they are multiple version of Garamond, e.g. Adobe’s one for instance.

TeX Live (and likely other TeX distributions) provides three open source implementations of Garamond, you can use any of them by including one of those three lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{garamondlibre}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
```

Those packages will set automatically the right packages/fonts settings in an engine independent fashion.

Comment: I tried you answer but the problem still exists

Comment: What do you mean? With my answer, you need to remove `\setmainfont{Garamond}`. Did you do that? What error do you have then?

Comment: No I didn't, If I applied your answer the whole document will be in Garamond right ? but there is a problem that some parts in my document have Arial font, how to achieve that ?

Comment: Also \usepackage{ebgaramond} results in Times New Roman font - \usepackage{garamondlibre} results in Arial font - \usepackage{CormorantGaramond} results in Gerogia font. Nothing results in Garamond font

Comment: please check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618666/font-manipulation-issue

Comment: Regarding achieving some part in Arial, you’ve figured it by yourself in your new question. Regarding why it does not work for you, I definitively don’t know…